# What is the proper way of handling errors that are thrown from withing a callback function?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, error-handling, callback

I am developing a NodeJS application and I am using mongoose for saving data into my MongoDB database.

My controller can take a `POST` request at the `/register` url with some data. That looks like this:

```
router.post("/register", async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const accountModel: IRegistrationAccount = {
    firstName: req.body.firstName,
    lastName: req.body.lastName,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
    repeatedPassword: req.body.repeatedPassword,
  };

  try {
    registerAccount(accountModel);
    res.status(OK).send("Registration successful.");
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(NOT_ACCEPTABLE).send(err);
  }
});
```

As you can see, I want to return an error message to the user so that they know exactly what went wrong. This is the `registerAccount` method:

```
export function registerAccount(accountModel: IRegistrationAccount) {
  if (accountModel.firstName.length === 0)
    throw "Your first name may not be empty.";

  if (accountModel.email.length < 3) throw "Your email is too short.";

  if (accountModel.password !== accountModel.repeatedPassword)
    throw "The passwords You entered don't match.";

  if (accountModel.password.length < 8) throw "Your password is too short.";

  const account = new Account(accountModel);
  account.save(function (err) {
    if (err) return logger.err(err);

    return logger.info("Created account.");
  });
}
```

When there is something wrong the the data that the user entered, I return an error message using throw, which is then later caught in the controller. The problem is: how do I know if the callback function inside `save` threw an error and how do I handle that error? This is my first time working with Node, I tried searching around but can't find a suitable answer.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`save` method can return `Promise` so you don't need to use a callback at all:

```js
export async function registerAccount(accountModel: IRegistrationAccount) {
  if (accountModel.firstName.length === 0)
    throw "Your first name may not be empty.";

  if (accountModel.email.length < 3) throw "Your email is too short.";

  if (accountModel.password !== accountModel.repeatedPassword)
    throw "The passwords You entered don't match.";

  if (accountModel.password.length < 8) throw "Your password is too short.";

  const account = new Account(accountModel);
  await account.save();
}
```

and add `await` at the line where you call this function:

```js
try {
    await registerAccount(accountModel);
    logger.info("Created account.")
    res.status(OK).send("Registration successful.");
  } catch (err) {
    logger.err(err)
    res.status(NOT_ACCEPTABLE).send(err);
  }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

I'd promisify `account` with util.promisify, and then return the Promise and `.catch` it in the caller:

```
return accountSavePromisified().then(() => {
  logger.info("Created account.");
});
```

```
try {
    registerAccount(accountModel)
        .then(() => {
            res.status(OK).send("Registration successful.");
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            // Catch asynchronous errors (thrown by `.save`):
            res.status(NOT_ACCEPTABLE).send(err);
        })
} catch (err) {
    // Catch synchronous errors (thrown by your validator):
    res.status(NOT_ACCEPTABLE).send(err);
}
```

If you don't care about differentiating errors thrown by `.save` from errors thrown by your validator, you could also `await` the call of `registerAccount` instead of calling `.then` on it.

You could also consider making the control flow a bit easier to understand by *returning* error strings from `registerAccount` instead of throwing, eg `return 'Your first name may not be empty.'`:

```
const result = registerAccount(accountModel);
if (typeof result === 'string') {
  res.status(NOT_ACCEPTABLE).send(result);
  return;
}
result.then(() => {
  res.status(OK).send("Registration successful.");
})
.catch((err) => {
  res.status(NOT_ACCEPTABLE).send(result);
});
```

Comment: In 2020 you can avoid the use of `.catch()` and use the normal `try / catch` with async/await.